# gVim always opens in workspace #4

Tags: unity, gvim

I'm a Windows guy who recently switched to Ubuntu ... I use gVim for programming. Every time I launch gVim from the applications menu or from the right-click context menu, it opens in workspace #4, no matter what workspace I'm in (usually I'm just in #1, still getting used to that concept).

If I run gvim from a terminal, it stays in the same workspace, so I'm guessing this has something to do with the Unity desktop (?) How can I make gVim open in the current workspace?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Have you experimented with anything like `wmctrl` or `devilspie` by any chance? Just asking, because those programs can control window placement like that. Also, do you have a custom gvim desktop file under `~/.local/share/applications/` ?

Comment: No haven't used either of those, and don't have a custom desktop file there. Just the regular `_vimrc` file. But your comment made think of running gVim without anything in `_vimrc`, and guess what, when I do that it opens in the current workspace. I'll go through and see if I can isolate what was causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this was the culprit in the `_vimrc` file:

```
set lines=999
set columns=999
```

Thanks @geirha for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to pass on maximized windows.

I do it the following way to have a maximized window in the current workspace:

```
function! MaximizeWindow()
  set lines=999
  set columns=999
endfunction

autocmd GUIEnter * :call MaximizeWindow()
```